# DRY in model to capture all values

Tags: python, django

Is there a cleaner way to get the "ALL" values instead of hardcoding them all? For example, if I added a new value here, I'd need to manually add in that item as well:

```
class EntitySharedLinkPermission(models.Model):

    OFF = None
    COMPANY_VIEW = "Company View"
    COMPANY_EDIT = "Company Edit"
    PUBLIC_VIEW = "Public View"
    PUBLIC_EDIT = "Public Edit"
    ALL_PERMISSIONS = [
     EntitySharedLinkPermission.OFF,
     EntitySharedLinkPermission.COMPANY_VIEW,
     EntitySharedLinkPermission.COMPANY_EDIT,
     EntitySharedLinkPermission.PUBLIC_VIEW,
     EntitySharedLinkPermission.PUBLIC_EDIT
    ]
```

Comment: How about `EntitySharedLinkPermission.All`?

Comment: At a minimum, you don't need to type `EntitySharedLinkPermissions` repeatedly inside `ALL_PERMISSIONS`. Since you're already in the class definition, you can just type `ALL_PERMISSIONS = [OFF, COMPANY_VIEW, COMPANY_EDIT, PUBLIC_VIEW, PUBLIC_EDIT]` for the same effect.